# Tab is not working

Tags: admin, import, tabs, magento-2.1.3

I am trying to create a **form** which consists of a **file** type field to **import** my **data** in **csv** file.

This is what I have done so far,

I tried simple form but my validations on the **file type field** were not working, so I rather thought of using **tabs** , thinking that it would work well but unfortunately tab was not getting displayed at all.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="RB\CheckDelivery\Block\Adminhtml\Import\Edit" name="rb_zipcode_import"></block>
        </referenceContainer>

          <referenceContainer name="left">
            <block class="RB\CheckDelivery\Block\Adminhtml\Import\Edit\Tabs" name="rb_zipcode_import_tabs">
                <block class="RB\CheckDelivery\Block\Adminhtml\Import\Edit\Tab\Import" name="rb_zipcode_import_tab_main"/>
                    <action method="addTab">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">import_sections</argument>
                        <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">rb_zipcode_import_tab_main</argument>
                    </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/RB/CheckDelivery/Block/Adminhtml/Import/Edit/Tab/Import.php**

```
namespace RB\CheckDelivery\Block\Adminhtml\Import\Edit\Tab;

class Import extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
    {

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
         * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
         * @param array $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
           array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
            parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory,$data);
        }

        /**
         * Prepare form
         *
         * @return $this
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
         */
        protected function _prepareForm()
        {        
            $form = $this->_formFactory->create();

            $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('zipimports_');

            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Import')]);

            $fieldset->addField(
                'zipcodes',
                'file',
                [
                    'name' => 'zipcodes',
                    'label' => __('Please choose a file to import'),
                    'required' => true
                ]
            );

            $this->setForm($form);

            return parent::_prepareForm();
        }

        /**
         * Prepare label for tab
         *
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
         */
        public function getTabLabel()
        {
            return __('ZIP Code');
        }

        /**
         * Prepare title for tab
         *
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
         */
        public function getTabTitle()
        {
            return __('ZIP Code');
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function canShowTab()
        {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function isHidden()
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

**app/code/RB/CheckDelivery/Block/Adminhtml/Import/Edit.php**

```
namespace RB\CheckDelivery\Block\Adminhtml\Import;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
{

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'RB_CheckDelivery';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_import';

        parent::_construct();

       $this->removeButton('reset');
       $this->removeButton('back');
        $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Save Zipcodes'));

    }

     /**
     * Get form save URL
     *
     * @see getFormActionUrl()
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSaveUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('checkdelivery/*/saveImport', ['_current' => true,'active_tab' => '']);
    }

}
```

**app/code/RB/CheckDelivery/Block/Adminhtml/Import/Edit/Tabs.php**

```
namespace RB\CheckDelivery\Block\Adminhtml\Import\Edit;

/**
 * Admin page left menu
 */
class Tabs extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('import_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(__('Zipcode Information'));
    }
}
```

Let me know what I am missing here of if there's an alternative way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging this is what i found in my log files :

**[2017-01-09 10:28:13] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'rb_zipcode_import_tabs' element cannot be added as child to 'left', because the latter doesn't exist [] []**

So basically the solution is to add a layout type to your xml page configuration.

i.e **layout="admin-2columns-left"**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"></page>
```